# Как лучше всего использовать фрагмент?

Tags: android, android-studio

В своём приложении я использую фрагменты для отображения новостей. Новости различаются по тематике, но их "схема" одинакова. То есть по сути можно использовать один класс фрагмента. Я бы хотел уточнить, какой путь лучше выбрать:

1. Сделать абстрактный класс фрагмента, и сделать для каждой тематики маленький класс-наследник, затем соответственно просто переключать нужные фрагменты.
2. Сделать всего один класс фрагмента, но передавать в него переменную, обозначающую тип тематики через механизм передачи аргументов в фрагмент. Затем при выборе тематик  удалять фрагмент из контейнера и добавлять снова с новыми аргументами.
3. Аналогично второму пути, но не удалять фрагмент, а как-то динамически передавать в него тип тематики, и перезагружать его (через detach/attach).

Какой способ лучше по производительности и целесообразности или между ними нет особой разницы?

Comment: что значит схема просто внутри меняется контент? но вопрос хороший, я в ответе постараюсь разъяснить.

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei меняется ссылка (RSS-канал), откуда берутся новости. Общая схема новости одинакова: заголовок, описание, дата публикации, ссылка на полную новость

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из 3-х вариантов более произовдительный будет `3-й`, но не факт что он вам подойдет. Это будет выглядеть что-то типо удаления вью фрагмента и сново вызова onCreatView, чтоб это инициировать делают детач и аатач в 1 транзакции. 
Например так:

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().detach(this).attach(this).commit();
```

Если вы хотите, иметь бек стек фрагментов, для серфинга по прочитанным новостям, то нужно уже делать логику добавления, обновления фрагментов, очищения фрагментов из FragmentManager это немного посложнее.

Но Если вам необходимо просто показать новый контент в этом же фрагменте, то самый эффективный вариант не пересоздавать его! а перерисовать только те элементы, в которых обновился контент(данные), будьт то фото, текст и тд.
Для этого достаточно вызвать set для View.